# Show that the sequence {(2n)/(n+2)} converges to 2 using the \epsilon definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

[image: My work]

And I based my work on the following example:

[image: The example]

Comment: My first question would be, "You seem to have this nailed -- what's the problem?" :) -- I would point out, though, that you should really say
$$\left| \frac{2n}{n+2} - 2 \right| < \epsilon \ \ \forall n \ge N.$$
So add on $\forall n \ge N$. I realise that their proof doesn't say that, but without it you haven't actually said what $n$ is at the end; you need to make clear that $n \ge N$. Other than that, excellent. :)

Comment: @SmileySam
I have added it at the very end of my proof.  That is where I have to add the ''for  all"  quantifier, correct?

Comment: I can't actually see any change, but the only change needed is the last line. :) -- Otherwise, good job!